# copy sharepoint intranet site

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, layout

I am about to create a custom sharepoint layout for a client, to make it look like their company page.
I don't have any experience in sharepoint whatsoever, so this is going to be a challenge, but that's how you learn.

A question on this; Can the client copy their entire sharepoint site, send it to me and then I can use it on my local sharepoint installation, create the new layout and send the new layout back to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backup/Restore a site collection is your answer.
See this link for reference:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gayanpeiris/archive/2008/03/16/back-up-and-restore-by-using-stsadm.aspx